# Assasin creed installation failed in pc

Tags: technical-issues, assassins-creed-3

When installing Assassins' Creed, the DirectX setup (DXSETUP.exe) came up with an error:

```
.NET Framework 3.5 is required.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Where are you installing from?

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the missing .NET Framework; the software pre-requisite for DirectX.
The two commonly used releases are [3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21) (which is the one you may be looking for) and [4.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) (for newer apps running on Windows 7/8).

After that, run the DirectX installer again, it shouldn't ask you to install .NET Framework 3.5 again, and go on with the installation as usual.

Comment: 8/8.1 comes with 3.5 so he's running 7.